# Highlight of ListView items without setting the focus

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

In my situation there is a textbox that I am typing in it and then there is a listView that jumps to the item I am typing in the text box so the FOCUS should always be in the text box so I can continue typing! But as I said when it is selecting the item in the ListView I want that item to be  highlighted with BLUE background as other standard highlights in Windows forms. Is there a way to do this?

thanks.

Comment: Yes but I believe it will go grey when focused on the listview is lost

Comment: yes, grey... I am trying to make it the same highlight color as other Windows contorls..for example when we selectAll a textbox .. the same color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at setting the [ListViewItemBackColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.backcolor%28VS.71%29.aspx), you could change it as they type so it looks as though it has been selected, when it reality all it has is a blue background.

Or you could try setting the colour of the background to blue AND selecting the item and then setting the focus back to the textbox so they can continue typing, although it may not happen quickly enough so key presses may be lost but you'd have to try it and see how well it works.

Comment: I just want one item - same as it is typed in the textBox - to be highlighted .. but this sounds to color all the listView items.

Comment: No it's for individual items in the list

Comment: ahh, ok, something like this:             lview.Items[0].BackColor = Color.Blue;
            lview.Items[0].ForeColor = Color.White;
but now the problem is that I have to keep track of cells getting clikced by the user and take care of returning their color back to normal once they get out ou selection.... any simpler idea?

Comment: Ok, lets see what you're trying to do. Why do you want them selected in the first place?

Comment: @ w69rdy:there is Selection Form.it has a text box and this list view.when user start typing in the text box it tries to auto complete what user has typed or find the closest match to it.but then I want the same thing to be highlighted in the list view.this list view actually has the list of all available items that the user can find and is currently searching for in the text box.but If I move the focus to the listview then user cannot type anymore in the text box which is wrong!I want while the user is typing the listview also start re acting to that and if found something then Highlight it

Comment: In that case, why not use the autocomplete feature of the combobox to do all that for you? Does it need to be in a listview for any reason?

Answer (score 0):

This question is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531395/selecting-an-item-in-a-listview-control-winforms-while-not-having-the-focus), so I'm giving the same answer.

Manually setting `ListViewItem.BackColor` is not good a solution, especially if you want the item to get the `selected` state, because it only works on unselected items. So you had to take care of several situations to make it look right in all cases (really select the item as soon as the ListView gets focus, undo the color changes, and so on...)

It seems the only good way is to use Ownerdraw or an extended ListView like [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/).

I was looking for the same and I still hope for a better/smarter solution, or at least a nice and short Ownerdraw implementation. **Update** - I found one: use `DataGridView` instead, for details see above duplicate.

Comment: Please don't duplicate content. Just write a comment highlighting that this is a duplicate so it can get closed as such. You'll get more traffic to your original answer that way.